# Change style of shinydashboard box with shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinywidgets

I am trying to change the color of the shinydashboard boxes according to the tab the user is in.
To do so, I am getting the input value from a tabsetPanel, and try to change the css of the box-header class with shinyjs. Unfortunately none of my trials have succeeded. Here is a reproducible example (the color does not adapt to the tab yet but I'll do that in a second part)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard(),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "mytab",
    tabPanel("First",
             shinydashboard::box(status = "primary",
                                 title = "mybox",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                                 sliderInput("orders", "Orders", min = 1, max = 2000, value = 650)
                                 )),
  tabPanel("Second", p("Second tab"))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$mytab,{
    shinyjs::runjs("$('.box-header').css('background', 'red');")
    shinyjs::runjs("$('.box.box-solid.box-primary > .box-header').attr('style', 'background:red !important');")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried all combinations between the first and the second call to runjs but all of them failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing `useShinyjs()` in the `ui`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard(),
  #tabBox( id = "mytab", width=6, title = "My Test Plot",
  tabsetPanel(id = "mytab",
    tabPanel("First", value="tab1",
             shinydashboard::box(status = "primary",
                                 title = "mybox",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                                 sliderInput("orders", "Orders", min = 1, max = 2000, value = 650)
             )),
    tabPanel("Second", value="tab2", p("Second tab"),
             shinydashboard::box(status = "warning",
                                 title = "mybox",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                                 sliderInput("orders2", "Orders", min = 1, max = 2000, value = 950)
             ))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$mytab,{
    if (input$mytab=="tab1"){
      shinyjs::runjs("$('.box-header').css('background', 'red');")
      shinyjs::runjs("$('.box.box-solid.box-primary > .box-header').attr('style', 'background:red !important');")
    } else if (input$mytab=="tab2"){
      shinyjs::runjs("$('.box-header').css('background', 'blue');")
      shinyjs::runjs("$('.box.box-solid.box-primary > .box-header').attr('style', 'background:blue !important');")
    }
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: We don't need to run multiple runjs. Multiple lines can be wrapped in a single runjs

Answer (score 0):

https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css

```
    ## ui.R ##
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Custom font"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
    )
  )
)
```